# Escape sequence in yaml

Tags: yaml

What are the characters that need to be escaped in yaml and how can I do that?

For example how can I escape characters in the following code

```
command : [ "perl", "-e", " '$mb = 2000; $b = $mb * 1024 * 1024; open MEM, '\''>'\'', \$memfile; seek MEM, $b - 1, 0; print MEM '\''A'\''; close MEM; printf "$mb MB memory is occupied, press ENTER to release: "; <STDIN>; undef $memfile; printf "Memory released";' " ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using YAML's folded scalar feature you can make this much more readable. The `>` folding indicator will "fold" all of the indented lines into a single line (with a space in between each).

```
command:
  - perl
  - -e
  - >
    $mb = 2000;
    $b = $mb * 1024 * 1024;
    open MEM, '>', \$memfile;
    seek MEM, $b - 1, 0;
    print MEM 'A';
    close MEM;
    printf "$mb MB memory is occupied, press ENTER to release: ";
    <STDIN>;
    undef $memfile;
    printf "Memory released";
```

You'll notice that the above isn't wrapped in single-quotes like it is in your code. I'm assuming that whatever tool consumes this file will correctly escape each part. I may be incorrect on that point, but the fact that the command is separated into elements of a sequence (YAML parlance for array) strongly suggests that the tool that consumes this will consider each element a single argument and correctly escape/quote it accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Use the backslash: \

Here's the spec/list of characters to escape: http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2517668